# Created a sitemap using the modules views and views data

Tags: views

I just created a sitemap using the modules views and views data export. How do I add

tag in the header.

[image]

thank you

Comment: <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the `views-data-export-xml-header.tpl.php` that corresponds to the view your wanting to edit. To find this out, click on Advanced, Theme, and then Information. You're looking for a line like this:

> Alternative style: views-data-export-xml-header.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--test.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--views-data-export.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--test--views-data-export.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--default.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--default.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--views-data-export-1.tpl.php, views-data-export-xml-header--test--views-data-export-1.tpl.php

Pick a filename and make the changes. **Note that if you're looking to wrap the results in additional tags, you'll need to override both the header and the footer files.**

You'd change:

```
// Short tags act bad below in the html so we print it here.
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
?>

<<?php print $root_node; ?>>
```

To also include any other information:

```
// Short tags act bad below in the html so we print it here.
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
?>

<<?php print $root_node; ?>>
<header-data>
</header-data>
```

Comment: thank you, I followed the instructions. So I copy the file to the templates folder of my theme and added the above lines. Should we add lines to template.php?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.

Comment: ok it works, I have another question. If I create a sitemap news and more of it, how to set a second header?

Comment: Different question: Is there a reason why you are not using the [XML sitemap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap)?

Comment: I love not just try to get views views data export. I'm not sure that xmlsitemap handles images

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'm not sure that it supports it, but I'd think that it'd ultimately be a better place for your time and effort, that is: creating a patch for XML Sitemap than for trying to build something with views. But hey, that's just my 2¢. :)

Comment: I managed to create multiple sitemap divide by content type with a view. So far so fontionne perfectly. But I would like to add the image and the alt tag. I think the best and doing a rewrite of the output of image field like this
<image:image><image:loc>[field_image_1]</image:loc><image:title>[field_image_1-alt]</image:title></image:image>
but all the tags will not be displayed. How to what is displayed?
A second solution would be to create a custom text box, but the label are ignored. :(